# Many times display error Service Temporarily Unavailable. what is the final solution of this situation

Tags: magento-1.7

Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Many times display error come in a week. I have to delete maintains flag again & again. what is the final solution of this situation.